# formulation of FIND () criteria in SUMIF in Excel for Mac

Tags: excel, find, criteria

I can't figure out the correct syntax for the following case:

I'm having a cell (A1) containing a list of ids of different groups. And a list of groups and their values  (A3:B6)

I want to use a SUMIF function to sum the values for the groups of which A1 contains the id. So for the case below the outcome should be 200+400+600 = 1200.

```
   A            B
1  02 01 04
2
3  01           200
4  02           400
5  03           100
6  04           600
```

I tried this, which doesn't work, but I can't find how to do this.

```
SUMIF(A3:A6;NOT(ISERR(FIND("";A1));B3:B6)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can use `SUMIF` here, try using this formula

`=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(MATCH("*"&A3:A6&"*";A1;0))+0;B3:B6)`

You match `A3:A6` with A1, using wildcards and sum every `B3:B6` value where `MATCH` finds a match and therefore returns a number

Comment: Works nicely. Thanks!